Why was the Triwizard Cup itself, and not some other item, placed at the centre of the maze in the third task?
Triwizard Cup was the winning trophy of the Triwizard tournament. And in a way, the first person to reach it would lift it. There could have been any magical object at the centre of the maze for the task. The task was not winners take all like the first to reach the cup might still not win the cup if he/she is more than 50 points behind the top performer before the start of 3rd task. So why was the winning trophy placed at the centre of the maze?

Erm, yes? Not sure what you're asking here since the quote literally answers your question. The last task is a task, not a winner-take-all final heat.

@Valorum As the cup is placed at the end of maze, it looked like whoever reaches the cup first is the winner of the cup as he will lift the cup. If it was just a task, there could have been placed any other thing.

But the quotations you provided already prove that this isn't the case and instead it's about the highest total. Why they chose to use the cup as the destination in the maze is anybody's guess. Pretty similar to the Golden Snitch actually — catching it ends the game and awards a lot of points but doesn't necessarily win the game for your team.

My question is what is the point of placing the cup as the finishing point of maze? Isn't that the winning trophy of the tournament? And someone who is winning the third task is lifting it. The centre of the maze could have been any object and the cup should be given to the winner only. Cup being in the centre of the maze gives clear impression that it is winners take all.

Edited the question. @Valorum

@DhruvSharma - It's possible that the point score was sufficiently close that whoever got to the cup would win enough points to be the winner, hence the cup is an appropriate target.

Or it could be a slip up by the author.  Its only a story.

https://archives.sluggy.com/book.php?chapter=55#2008-04-17

You're right that it would make a poor choice of target if there was a chance that whoever reached it might not be the winner. (Maybe, as Valorum said, they only do this when the scores are close enough that it's guaranteed they will be). Out of universe, I'd say it's the same reason the Golden Snitch exists: to make Harry the hero.

I think it's more symbolism than anything. Your goal is to get the cup - both of that round and the entire game. If you were behind you might push harder to get to the physical cup rather than some random item?

The cup may as well be the random item. There's nothing special about the cup, except as the physical representation of winning the tournament.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193275/how-does-one-win-the-triwizard-tournament
